# Collect Jinja2 tag calls when parsing

Tags: javascript, python, templates, jinja2

I'd like to scan the body of my page and collect the body of all calls to a certain Jinja2 tag. With each, I'd like to extract the content and use it in the `<head>` element when setting up some Javascript. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(since I can't post comments yet...)

Could you provide an example of what you want to do? It sounds like something that may be implementable using `call` and `caller()` ([doc'm here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#call)). If it's something more 'meta' than that, you could probably use Jinja2's builtin parser (via Environment.parse) to extract the information you want. An extension may also be an option, via a passive `filter_stream` ([see here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#extension-api)).